# No handler for type [join] declared on field

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I tried to create an index with join datatype on new AWS Elasticsearch 6.0.

Following instruction on Elasticsearch 6.0 document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/parent-join.html

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": { 
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "question": "answer" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I received the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "No handler for type [join] declared on field [my_join_field]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [doc]: No handler for type [join] declared on field [my_join_field]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "No handler for type [join] declared on field [my_join_field]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I am wondering if I'm missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are testing this against Elasticsearch 6?

Comment: I tripple check that. One the same instance, I cannot create more than 1 type. The old parent child mapping is not working as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same problem. Root cause is a missing module on the ElasticSearch service packaged by AWS.
If you compare the configuration of a local installation and the one provided by AWS you will that this module is missing:

```
{
      "name" : "parent-join",
      "version" : "6.0.0",
      "description" : "This module adds the support parent-child queries and aggregations",
      "classname" : "org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin",
      "has_native_controller" : false,
      "requires_keystore" : false
}
```

Feature is now available in AWS ES 6.0

Comment: please share the answer when you got it

Comment: Answer from the support is: "I have gone ahead and looked further into this as well as gotten feedback directly from the Amazon Elasticsearch Service development team.  They did confirm that at this time the parent-join module is not available in Amazon ES Service version 6.0 but they are working to add support. It is not enabled in the initial 6.0 release but they are investigating getting it added as soon as possible.  We can not, unfortunately, provide an ETA for this feature at this time.  I encourage you to keep an eye on our "What's New" page for the service [1] for any future updates."

Comment: Feature is now available in AWS ES 6.0: to apply it on existing cluster, you have to rebuild it: for exemple increase node instance type, apply, then decrease node instance type.